# Can't set max for seekbar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the max for my seekbar but it still defaults to 100.

XML

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarRow1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:progress="0"
/>
```

Defining and setting max

```
final SeekBar seekBarRow1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarRow1);
seekBarRow1.setMax(50);
```

Don't know if it is effecting it but here is my listener

```
seekBarRow1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
    {
        progress = progress * 2;
        numWeightsRow1 = progress;
        numWeightsRow1 = numWeightsRow1 / 2;
        numRow1.setText("" + progress);
        updateWeight();
    }
});
```

I have tried adding to my seekbar in xml but it still defaults to 100.

```
android:max="50"
```

Comment: *but it still defaults to 100.*, how do you know ?

Comment: because when i push it to my device the slide bar goes from 0-100. I want it to go from 0 - 50.

Comment: where are you reading `100`? In `numRow1.setText("" + progress);`?

Comment: You called ` progress = progress * 2;`,so the text will be 0-100.

Comment: Yeah blackbelt made me just realize that. I knew this had to be something simple. I changed the max to 25 which makes it 50 now. Thanks.

Comment: does this line `progress = progress * 2;` ring any bell ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell, For What purpose you want to use SeekBar?
I mean, do you want to use SeekBar with MediaPlayer or with any other widget?
Suppose if you want to use SeekBar with MediaPlayer, then below is the best example for SeekBar with SeekBarChangeListener

[Seekbar: Android Online/Local Audio Media Player with Play/Pause, Rewind, Forward, Previous and Next functionality with Seekbar](https://github.com/kalpeshmayani/MediaPlayer)

Comment: I am using a seek bar to allow users to choose an even number between 0 and 50. The user input is then used in equations. Nothing to do with media.

Comment: @th3ramr0d You mean to say, you want functionality like RangeSeekBar, Then this link might help you https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar